# Why is malloc giving wrong string , when while working?

Tags: c, malloc

```
char* my_strdup(char* param_1){
    char *p;
    int n = sizeof(param_1);

    p = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char)*n));
    int i = 0;
    while(i<n){
        p[i] = param_1[i];
        i++;
       
    }
    return p;

}
```

while is not brocked in the end
how can i fix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfMZz.png)

Comment: Change `sizeof (param_1)` to `strlen(param_1) + 1`, which is the actual length of the string (including NUL `'\0'`) instead of the size of a `char *`. As a side note, make `param_1` a `const char *` instead because you're not modifying it.

Comment: welcome to SO. `malloc` does not give any string at all. It just returns an address. And you are using wrong size for allocation. `sizeof param_1` only yields the size of a pointer which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(T)` gives the amount of memory that an object of type T requires. If T is a variable, then the type of this variable is used.

With `char* param_1`, expression `sizeof(param_1)` gives you the memory that type `char*` requires, i.e. the size of a pointer. This is likely to be always `8` (the size a pointer needs on a 64bit machine). But it is definitely not the length of the string to which `param_1` points to.

correct would be...

```
int n = strlen(param_1) + 1;
```

The `+ 1` is required, because every string needs an additional terminating character at the end. By `+1`, this is copied together with the actual content.